# Ubuntu one deleted files in cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete, cloud

I stopped syncing a folder in one pc and then deleted it but the folder is deleted from the ubuntu one cloud storage as well, what went wrong?

Comment: How did you 'stop syncing' it exactly?

Comment: I right clicked the folders that where synced and clicked on stop syncing, then I deleted them from the pc. I'm guessing maybe cause there was no other pc that had downloaded those folders yet? It shouldn't do that I think but just maybe that's how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-clicking on a synchronized folder in Nautilus, and choosing "Stop synchronizing on Ubuntu One" will result in the folder and its contents being removed from the server. It doesn't mean "only remove the connection for this computer, to this folder."

If you wish to unsubscribe a synchronized folder on a computer, you can do so by opening the Ubuntu One control panel application from the launcher, and unchecking the box under the 'Sync Locally?' column on the Folders tab, for the folder you wish to no longer sync to the local machine. Or, you can also use the `u1sdtool` utility on the command line, to unsubscribe a folder or share.

Comment: Thx, it is rather misleading though, I think. it'd be better if at least there be a warning making sure the user want to delete the files from the cloud. If I had another PC with the folder synced would it also delete from the cloud and stopped syncing on the other PC?

Comment: Yes, the stop synchronizing context menu item in the file manager will delete it from the server, and so no other machines will be able to synchronize it either. they will no longer know about it, but the files won't be automatically deleted from them, if they did have it synchronized.